# How does the function work without any return type

Tags: function

this function works without any return type. But how that's my question....

```js
void factorial(int i_value){
    int fact=1,j;
        for(int j=2*i_value-1;j>=1;j--){
                fact=fact*j;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what are you want to return?
perhaps the fact

```
int factorial(int i_value){
    int fact=1,j;
    for(int j=2*i_value-1;j>=1;j--){
        fact=fact*j;
    }
    return fact;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I asked something different. The code works without any return type. But how is it possible??

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean

Comment: Do you want to ask why a function can have no return value

Comment: No this function works without any return value. but why does it really work, If you want you can check the function, it returns value without the return type.